# Block that returns a block without typedef

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I can't figure out how to do this without using typedefs:

```
typedef void(^HLBlock)(void);

- (void)whatever
{
    HLBlock (^genBlock)(int) = ^(int tryCount){
        HLBlock b1 = [[^{
            NSLog(@"tryCount=%i", tryCount);
        } copy] autorelease];
        return b1;
    };

    genBlock(10);
}
```

It seems quite silly that I need to declare HLBlock as a typedef for void (^)(void), but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do this without the typedef.  What is the correct return type of genBlock?

Thanks!
Jamie

Comment: Unless you're in ARC you need to copy that block when returning it.

Comment: @KevinBallard of course, but it should still be clear what I'm asking I hope.

Comment: Just so you know, `dispatch_block_t` is already a typedef for `void (^)(void)`.

Comment: @KenThomases, excellent point, and quite understandable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the syntax with no typedefs, but I argue it's so unreadable that the typedef is strongly preferred:

```
void(^(^genBlock)(int))() = ^(int tryCount){
  void (^b1)() = ^{
    NSLog(@"tryCount=%i", tryCount);
  };
  return b1;
};

void(^aBlock)() = genBlock(10);
aBlock();
```

Comment: And here's the cdecl description: http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/?q=void%28%5E%28%5EgenBlock%29%28int%29%29%28%29

Comment: @RobNapier Is that really the simplest syntax?   Why doesn't this work: (void(^)(void))(^genBlock)(int) = ^(int tryCount) { ... }  I ask b/c what you wrote does not seem equivalent to how it would be with a typedef as compared to the example I gave in this comment.

Comment: This is the simplest syntax. You need to think carefully through how the function pointer syntax really works to understand it. Follow Kevin's link for some exploration. And see Matt Gallagher's excellent writeup: http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/10/ugly-side-of-blocks-explicit.html

Comment: +1 Ok thanks, just wanted to make sure.  Thanks for the tips!

Comment: Xcode complained when I tried to declare a block that returns a block inside a method argument (silly!), so I thought Xcode/clang/Objective-C just didn't support returning blocks. I couldn't believe that. Thanks to your answer I discovered that Objective-C/C are really powerful languages — so powerful that they're incredibly difficult when you start writing complex constructions. I'll stick with `typedef void(^CCSimpleBlock)(void)`. :-p